# Need help merging disconnected git repos

Tags: git

I'm trying to merge two repos back into one.

Quite a while ago, I had a repo that was very slow and instead of doing maintenance on it I just moved the .git folder to a backup and then did a new git init to start fresh. Now I'd like to undo that if possible. The first commit of the new repo does not match the last commit of the old repo. Quite a few files changed on that new initial commit.

I’m thinking I need to set up the new repo as a remote to the old repo and then rebase that new first init onto the old repo master? I’m quite new to git and don’t have any merge experience.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The procedure you suggest is almost right, but you won't be able to rebase - you'll need to reparent instead.  See `git filter-branch` docs under `--parent-filter`; it has examples of several ways to do it.  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mark Adelsberger. Here's what I did based on your recommendation:

- I'm in the original repo.
- I ran `git remote add repo-b <path to repo>` to add the newer repo as a remote.
- I ran `git fetch repo-b` to fetch those references.
- I then ran `git replace --graft <repo-b init id> <original repo last commit id>`
- I then ran `git pull repo-b`

This seems to have worked nicely.